# How to use Spray JSON serializer in abstract way?

Tags: scala, akka-http

Any idea why this code doesn't work? I'm trying to have `serialize` method to all my exceptions to avoid the need for pattern matching for every exception. With the code below, I just need to `case ex:MarshallableException => ex.serialize`

The below code can run stand-alone. It will print `Start...  Serialization Failure shared.utils.InvalidID` :(

```
import scala.util.{Failure, Success}
import akka.http.scaladsl.marshalling.{Marshaller, Marshal}
import akka.http.scaladsl.marshallers.sprayjson.SprayJsonSupport._
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.ResponseEntity
import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global


trait MarshallableException{
  def serialize: Future[ResponseEntity]
}

case class InvalidID(error:String, code: String= "6001")  extends Exception with MarshallableException {
  import Exceptions._

  override def serialize: Future[ResponseEntity] = {
    Marshal(this).to[ResponseEntity]
  }
}

object Exceptions extends DefaultJsonProtocol{

  implicit val invalidIDFormat = jsonFormat2(InvalidID.apply)

}

object Test extends App{
  val ex = new InvalidID("Test exception")
  println("Start...\n")
  ex.serialize.onComplete{
    case Success(e) => println(e.toString())
    case Failure(f) =>
      println("Serialization Failure " + f.toString)
  }
}
```

Comment: you should probably paste the exception you are getting, and where.

Comment: Update the code so it can run stand-alone. Can you please check it now? Thanks